# How to engrave an image on an another texture

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

What's the best way to engrave/emboss an image on top of a texture? For example if I have smooth metal buckle and want a logo engraved in it and give the engraved part a brushed texture?

[image]

Comment: Have you any experience using normal maps? Essentially I think that an image texture as a stencil to reveal the brushed metal in the area of the normal map would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a bump map out of stretched noise texture for brushed effect with a black and white mask of the logo also using it for any differences in material properties of the engraved part.

[image]

Edit: Sorry, I made a mess there. With bump darker is deeper, lighter sticks out, so the texture should be inverted - white is outside and black is inside. Then it can be mixed with the stretched noise and since we want the noise inside, the mix factor should be black(0) outside, white(1) inside and if we multiply it by a value, that value becomes the factor -1(white) multiplied by the value becomes the value. So it's possible to control the amount of stretched noise mixed in. You can also only mix the property values of one shader instead of mixing two shaders.

Comment: Thanks this works! But I don't quit understand the following:
- why is the image texture color connected to the factor of the mix shader 
- why is the bump map node connected to both the glossy nodes?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I updated the answer. Sorry to confuse you.

Comment: How can I make the carve/bump deeper?

Answer (score 2):

I think Martin Z answered best, but as an alternate bit on info I did this in using a 3d object as my logo. I added a plane and unwrapped it, added a disconnected image node set to UV and then added my torus as a 3d object to use as my design. I baked in Cycles using AO and then used this as my base for inverting the result, increasing the contrast with an RGB Curves node and plugging that into the mix node between two image textures. I also set that into a bump node to get the effect similar to Martin's. 
[image][image]